# Intents - How to check whether an intent is started or not?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to start an Activity using Intent. Below is the code using intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("rtmp:example"))            
startActivity(i);
```

I want to show a dialog when this intent cannot find a third party application.

How can I do this?

Below is my try and catch block code:

```
try {
    startActivity(i2);
} catch () {

    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    b.setMessage("You need MX player or VLC player to play the video.");
    b.create().show();
}
```

Comment: Have you test it with such a case? I thought Android would throw an exception if it can not find an activity.

Comment: I don't want to do that

Comment: Then can you catch that exception and show the dialog

Comment: Can you please provide the code

Comment: what happen when you tried your code with try - catch? Did you still have the force close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android `startActivity()` would throw `ActivityNotFoundException`. You should catch it and show the dialog:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("rtmp:example"))
try{            
    startActivity(i);
} catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    //show you message here
}
```